# Upload fails on google play even after adding android:debuggable="false"

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-manifest

I am trying to upload my apk to the google store and it says You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play.

I have added android:debuggable="false" and i am signing it in release mode with a unique key still I am getting the error. I am building using xamarin

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.mycompApp.MyApp" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
<application android:label="MyApp" android:icon="@drawable/Icon" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:debuggable="false">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="MainActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"></activity>
    <!-- Only C2DM servers can send messages for the app. If permission is not set - any other app can generate it -->
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: debuggable=false is the default value, so you shouldn't need to include it yourself. Maybe some action of your ant-build that is resetting this flag?

Comment: How do i check that? I am using xamarin to create the build. I am pointing to release mode and creating the build

Comment: Must be something wrong with the "building with xamarin" part. There is some documentation regarding debuggable [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment%2C_testing%2C_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/)

Comment: I have followed all the steps defined there and then built it. infact i even tried manually signing it and uploading still i am getting the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the androidmanifest.xml was showing some windows encoding instaed of  and this was not throwing any error in xamarin. i changed it to utf-8 and it got uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Studio doesn't always update well changes in AndroidManifest. I could solve the same issue by manually deleting the `Droid/obj/Release/android` folder in my project directory, then clean + build + package. The new package was accepted by Google Play.