# How do I generate Google Play Console upload key using Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, apk, visual-studio-2019, google-play-console

**SUMMARY**

I created an app App using Xamarin Form and Visual Studio 2019.

Folder/file structure:

```
[d] App
 |-[d] App
 |  |-[d] App
 |  |  |- ...
 |  |-[d] App.Android
 |  |  |- ...
 |  |-[d] App.iOS
 |     |- ...
 |-[f] App.sln
```

I finally got rid of all the errors and warnings and tried to upload APK to Google Play Console. I found multiple *.apk files and googled that I have to upload the one that has "-Signed" in its name. It resides in `App/App/App.Android/bin/Debug`. Upon the failed upload I got the following message:

> **Upload failed**
>
> You uploaded a debuggable APK or Android App Bundle. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play. [Find out more about debuggable APKs or Android App Bundles](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing.html#publishing-configure).
>
> You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle in release mode. [Find out more about signing](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).

**WHAT I DID**

I found one SO [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246848/upload-fails-on-google-play-even-after-adding-androiddebuggable-false) that says I should change my project from Debug mode to Release.

I found that, if I right-click App.Android in (VS) Solution Explorer and choose Properties, I can choose Android Options tab on the left and then "Configuration: Release". It didn't work. But there is also Android Package Signing tab on the left which has the "Sign the .APK file using the following keystore details" checkbox unchecked.

Before I delved into the latter, I also found that in Visual Studio top-most menu I can open "Build" and choose "Configuration Manager" where I can change "Active solution configuration" to "Release" which in change turn all three project to "Release". I did so and it still didn't work. (No new *.apk file was created)

In the last link in quoted message above I found instructions on how to create the key needed

> 1. In the menu bar, click Build > Build > Generate Signed Bundle/APK.
> 2. In the Generate Signed Bundle or APK dialog, select Android App Bundle or APK and click Next.
> 3. Below the field for Key store path, click Create new.
>      {so forth...}

but these are only for Android Studio not Visual Studio. Is there any way how to do it with Visual Studio?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/publishing/publishing-to-google-play/?tabs=macos

Comment: @s3c You could sharing your solution in answer and marke it. This will make answer searching easier and be beneficial to community members. Thank you~

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin can be annoying for newer users, especially if you have made any changes to the defaults unknowingly. And the release configuration in the default template creates a debuggable APK, so that's not helpful either.

Let's follow the steps to publish an app, and disable debugging from the Release APK:

1. Make sure you choose Android, Release configuration in the main window as shown.
   [image: Visual Studio Configuration showing Android release]
2. Then double click on the Android project to open the Project Options and navigate to Compiler. Make sure that for the "Release" Configuration selected, you change the Debug Information to "None". Don't forget to press OK and save the changes. [image: Android project settings showing None for debug configuration]
3. Rebuild All.
4. Right click on the Android project and select Archive for Publishing. [image: Visual Studio screenshot showing the Archive for publishing option]
5. Once archived, continue to Sign and Distribute as you were doing earlier.

Make sure to read the comments for more details!

Comment: My Visual Studio looks entirely different (VS19C on Win10), but the best clue was right clicking on App.Android and Archive. Upload signature is managed by Google in my case and upload of the created app worked like a charm. Also figured out two things if anyone else is stuck like I was. To edit code after publishing you have to set it back to Debug (Build > Configuration manager). To archive it again you then have up the version number and set it back to Release. Kudos

Comment: Hey s3c, I m glad you figured it out. I edited the answer so people look at your comment as well! :)