# Failed archiving Xamarin.Forms Android app, no keystone file

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-play

I am not really a mobile developer but this project was on the board and I was interested so I took it. I made several changes to this Xamarin.forms app and published the changes to the Apple App Store successfully but I am having an issue deploying to Google Play. I may very well not understand this process so bare with me.

I have access to a developer account, our store page, and an admin user account. On the apps console page on the production tab I am editing the current release. "Releases are signed by Google Play".

In Visual Studio for Mac 2022 v17.3 the project.mobile.droid package builds successfully every time with no errors (release is selected here). The android packaging format is set to tab, which is what I want. But when I try to archive for publishing I get the error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error XA4310: `$(AndroidSigningKeyStore)` file `C:/Users/tortis1/AppData/Local/Xamarin/Mono for Android/Keystore/prodensity/prodensity.keystore` could not be found. (XA4310) (Density.Mobile.Droid)
```

First thing I notice is `Users/tortis1/AppData`. Maybe I'm unaware of something but there is no `tortis1` in my `Users` folder so I have no idea how to track this down. I have looked for a keystore file in the project and I could find these in the Debug folder: android_debug_keystore.flag, android_debug_keystore.flag, and debug.keystore.

I have not set up any kind of singning rules or credentials in VS for Mac. Have I skipped some step or am I missing something? If you need any further information please let me know.

I have tried working through similar questions like this: [How do I generate Google Play Console upload key using Xamarin Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305914/how-do-i-generate-google-play-console-upload-key-using-xamarin-forms) , but I can't get it to archive at all.

Comment: Who owned this app before you?  You need to ask them where the keystore is kept.  It's the file containing the certificate used to sign apps for the Play store.

Comment: They no longer work here, haven't for over a year. I'm now learning that this is why no one wanted to take this project...

Comment: there are numerous existing questions on this subject:  https://www.google.com/search?q=google+play+lost+keystore+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Jason well part of my question was what I was missing. I was not aware that I "lost" my keystore file or I would have googled that... Thanks though.